# Como usar funções da classe A na classe B e vice-versa?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Olá, estou tentando fazer um jogo mas encontrei um problema onde não consigo solucionar, talvez a resposta seja bem besta, mas como eu estou meio atarefado, não consigo encontrar de jeito nenhum.

Esta é minha primeira classe ou Script, que controla o jogador

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public int speed;
public int score;

public bool isGrounded;
public bool isWalled;
public bool isDead;

public Text scoreText;

public Transform spawnPoint;

public Vector3 jumpHeight = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
public GameController gameScript;

Rigidbody rb;
Transform playerTrn;


public void Start () {

    isDead = false;
    isWalled = false;
    isGrounded = true;

    GameController gameScript = GetComponent<GameController>();
    playerTrn = GetComponent<Transform>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    score = 0;
    SetScoreText();

}

private void FixedUpdate () {

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        playerTrn.Translate(new Vector3(speed, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        playerTrn.Translate(new Vector3(-speed, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime);

    if (isGrounded && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
       rb.velocity = jumpHeight;
       isGrounded = false;
    }

    if (isDead == true)
    {
        gameScript.Restart();

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {
            isDead = false;

            Instantiate(playerTrn, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
        }
    }

}

public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        Die();
    }


}

public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Collector"))
    {
        score = score + 1;
        SetScoreText();
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

void SetScoreText()
{
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
}

public void Die()
{
    if (isDead == false)
    {
        isDead = true;
        rb.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    return;

}
```

E esta, é a classe GameController, que deveria controlar a parte de fora do jogador.

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject playerObject;
private PlayerController playerController;

public int retries;

public Text restartText;
public Text retriesText;

public void Start()
{
    playerController = GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    retries = 0;
    SetRetries();
}


public void SetRetries()
{
    retriesText.text = "Retries: " + retries.ToString();
}

public void Restart()
{
    restartText.text = "Restart [R]";
}
```

Atualmente, no momento em que o jogador entra em contato com o "Enemy" ele desaparece como deveria, mas o botão "[R] restart" não, já que ele é de outra classe. Já tentei fazer de algumas maneiras, mas estou muito enrolado e não lembro direito quais eram.
A ideia aqui é que o jogador morra, apareça o texto de "Restart" e após pressionar a tecla R ele retorne para a posição do "spawnPoint", que seria a posição inicial e contaria "+1" no texto de "Retries". Mas por algum motivo quando o Player morre, ele parece parar de funcionar, por isso tentei criar outro script para tratar essas situações, sem que o mesmo pare de funcionar.

**Gostaria de saber se eu posso seguir essa lógica, ou se tenho que fazer de outra maneira.**

Comment: Faz uns anos que não mexo com unity3d, então não lembro direito, mas a impressão que tenho é que se os dois scripts estão no mesmo objeto e dependem mutuamente um do outro, entãao seria mais fácil se fossem um script só. E talvez que aquele `rb.gameObject.SetActive(false);` no método `Die()` vá desativar o objeto que atua em ambos os scripts.

Comment: O primeiro script está ligado diretamente ao objeto "Player", o segundo script está em um objeto separado. rb.gameObject.SetActive(false); no método Die() é para desativar o Player, para que ele não possa se movimentar. Tentei de outras maneiras, como this.gameObject.SetActive(false); ou até mesmo chamando da outra classe, mas ele sempre "trava"